# Does built-in sensors vary from smartphone to smartphone?

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-sensors, smartphone

I am using machine learning to interpret sensor signals from my phone. When I used a specific phone (Samsung), I got accurate results. However, when I used another phone (HUAWEI), it appears that the result is different.

Is this because of the different configuration in these phones? Are they using different sensors for the same type (say, accelerometer)?

If they were different, what can I do to compensate for the difference. Say, I trained my algorithm with data from Samsung, what can I do so that the algorithm will still work with HUAWEI phones accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Build in sensors are vary from smartphone to smartphone. 
The sensors quality and accuracy depends on the cost of the smartphone. But the software results are pretty much accurate.
Refer the link it might be useful:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Accuracy_of_sensors_in_Android_devices

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Okay so it's different. What can I do to compensate for the difference. Say, I trained my algorithm with data from Samsung, what can I do so that the algorithm will still work with HUAWEI phones accurately?

Comment: you have to compute the deviation and then add it to your algorithm...for each mobile you have to do the same

Comment: Sorry, but how can I compute for the deviation?

Comment: go through the PID controller details you will able to get an Idea? How it works and how they minimize the deviation?

Comment: What do you mean by PID controller details?

Comment: Proportional-Integral-Derivative

Comment: Yes, but how will I do that exactly? :)

Comment: do one thing check your reading on the Samsung mobile use same software and see the deviation of readings on the other mobile, compare it that might be a small deviation mapping.Then add that deviation in your program i.e output reading this might works